# Accesing values from rails app in a python script using argparse

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, argparse

I am trying to run a python script using ruby on rails. I am trying to access the values from rails in python script using argparse. The code is like

**views/pages/home.html.erb**

```
<h1>My Home</h1>
<p>its where the  <%= @heart %></p>
```

**controllers/concerns/pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    our_input_text = "heart"
    @heart = `python3 lib/assets/python/heart.py "#{our_input_text}"`
  end
end
```

**lib/assets/python/heart.py**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--our_input_text', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
input = args.our_input_text
print(input + " is")
```

But on executing I am getting the following error

```
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
usage: heart.py [-h] [--our_input_text OUR_INPUT_TEXT]
heart.py: error: unrecognized arguments: heart
```

How argparse can be used to obtain the value passed from rails

Comment: Looks like `\`python3 lib/assets/python/heart.py "#{our_input_text}"\`` should be `\`python3 lib/assets/python/heart.py --our_input_text "#{our_input_text}"\`` since that is what the usage shows, what the argument parser appears to expect, and what the error seems to suggest (e.g. right now it is viewing "heart" as an argument rather than the value for an argument)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks . Its working now. Please upvote the questio so that others can get the answer.

Comment: In all honesty, while I glad that my comment solved this for you, I am more inclined to close the question as a typographical error. The usage for the CLI is fairly clear and the error received appears to indicate the issue (especially since I don't python at all).